# WebFont monotype causes white screen onLoaded

Tags: google-webfonts

Today we went online with [www.polypod.net](http://www.polypod.net) and we're having the problem that, when the font has loaded, the screen gets completely white for a while (1-2 seconds) and then the website is drawn. Loading fonts is always an issue so we have the opacity of the page on 0 till we really have the font loaded and then make a smooth fade in.

What worked during production is now broken and we're kind of stuck why that is.
We don't have this behavior when we comment out the monotype font.

Does anyone have experience with this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running into a problem called 'FOUT' short for 'Flash of unstyled texts'. Gotta love the internet for it's acronyms making it nearly impossible to find common problems. -.-

Here is a link to prevent this from the font provider we used
http://www.fonts.com/support/faq/fout

After all this there were still some occurrences of a white screen. A loaded script sets the html to `visibility: none;` so I changed the visibility of html to `visibility: visible !important;`.